# Capistrano Task to kill a process by port ONLY IF the process is running?

Tags: ruby, unix, capistrano

I pretty much need what my Question statement says, currently I have a **Capistrano task** that looks like this:

```
desc "stops private pub"
task :stop_private_pub do
  run "kill -9 $(lsof -i:9292 -t)"
end
before 'deploy', 'servers:stop_private_pub'
```

...And it works well when in fact the process in **port 9292** is running, The problem is that when the process *Isn't running* this task will FAIL! and it Halts the whole Deployment Process!

I'm not a UNIX Shell expert, nor am I a Capistrano master, so.. I really need help improving this Capistrano Task, Is there a way to **kill -9** only **if** the process is running?

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Capistrano's `capture` command (in V3 at least, probably a V2 equivalent) to grab the output from your lsof command, and then only if you get a PID run the kill command.

```
pid = capture 'lsof', '-i:9292', '-t'
if pid # ensure it's valid here
   run "kill -9 #{pid}" # make darn sure pid is an integer if you embed it
end
```

Comment: Good, I like this one! I came up with another solution but this one works. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
run "kill -9 $(lsof -i:9292 -t); true"
```

or add on error continue:

```
task :stop_web, :roles => :app, :on_error => :continue do
   run "dosomething.sh; true"
end
```